# Data-structure that stores unique elements but answers queries for another ordering in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, sorting, unique

is there a data structure, which stores its elements uniquely (for a given compare-Functor) but answers queries for the highest element in that data structure with respect to another compare-Function ?

For Example: I have a class with two properties :
1) the size
2) the value

I'd like to have a data structure which stores all elements uniquely regarding its size but answers queries for the element with the highest value.
Using std::set with a compare functor for the sizes gives me uniqueness but queries for the highest value will have linear runtime...
Is there a better way?

(I'll 'add elements then ask for the highest value' and keep iterating this until a certain termination point is reached)

Any information would be appreciated (papers etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Boost::MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)** comes to mind.

Comment: Hello, thank you everyone for your answers! It seems to me that this should/could be general knowledge, therefore I'll have to familiarize myself with the boost lib...

Comment: @Dane: it doesn't hurt ;) But I wouldn't have known of that particular lib if I hadn't searched for something similar some time before.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be achieved using the library [Boost.Multi-index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Check in particular [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort)  in the tutorial, which is very close to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) (k-dimensional tree)? In your case, k would be 2.

Comment: I guess... but it's much more complicated to implement that peterchen's solution